# Logging as JSON lines with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have developed a function to create log files with python into JSON line files:

```
import logging
import sys
from datetime import datetime


def log_start(log_prefix):
    now = datetime.now()
    log_id = str(now).replace(':', '').replace(' ', '').replace('.', '').replace('-', '')[:14]
    log_name = '/mnt/jarvis/logs/{}_{}.txt'.format(log_prefix, log_id)

    root = logging.getLogger()
    if root.handlers:
        root.handlers = []

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename=log_name, filemode='a+',
                        format='''{{"log_id":"{}", "created_date":"%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d", "action_text":"%(message)s"}}'''.format(
                            log_id),
                        datefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '''{{"log_id":"{}", "created_date":"%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d", "action_text":"%(message)s"}}'''.format(
            log_id),
        datefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    root.addHandler(handler)

    return log_name, log_id
```

And it works just fine. However, I run into issues if the logging message has things like new line characters or double quotes on the message, it is no longer valid JSON. Is there a way to make the `%(message)` be string that is a "valid JSON string" without me having to correct for it every time?

**EDIT**

An example of this issue, is that I want to see the traceback in the logs, so a traceback like this would cause issues because of the quotes and \n characters:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lego/bricks/tableau/workbook.py", line 65, in refresh_extracts
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '***REDACTED***' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/jarvis/event_triggered/refresh_dashboard.py", line 21, in refresh_dashboard
    workbook.refresh_extracts()
  File "/var/task/lego/bricks/tableau/workbook.py", line 73, in refresh_extracts
    traceback.format_exc()))
  File "/var/task/lego/power_functions/error_handling/graceful_fail.py", line 16, in graceful_fail
    raise RuntimeError('This is a graceful fail, notifications sent based on attributes.')
RuntimeError: This is a graceful fail, notifications sent based on attributes.
```

Comment: Can I see an example of invalid JSON that has the newlines / quotes like you describe? I'm curious what is happening with specific strings.

Comment: @JacobIRR please see my edit, good point, should have added that to start with

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally test and format your string to/from JSON as needed. Here I am checking for the specific `JSONDecodeError` that is often thrown during this case, but you can trap any kind of exception you like, or many of them. Consider building your message string with a check like this:

```
import json

bad_json = '''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lego/bricks/tableau/workbook.py", line 65, in refresh_extracts
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '***REDACTED***' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/jarvis/event_triggered/refresh_dashboard.py", line 21, in refresh_dashboard
    workbook.refresh_extracts()
  File "/var/task/lego/bricks/tableau/workbook.py", line 73, in refresh_extracts
    traceback.format_exc()))
  File "/var/task/lego/power_functions/error_handling/graceful_fail.py", line 16, in graceful_fail
    raise RuntimeError('This is a graceful fail, notifications sent based on attributes.')
RuntimeError: This is a graceful fail, notifications sent based on attributes.
'''
try:
    test_message = json.loads(bad_json) # this fails in the above case
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
    good_json = json.dumps({"message": bad_json})
    test_message = json.loads(good_json)

print(test_message)
```

Result (this can be dumped into more readable text using `json.dumps(your_message_string)` if you like):

```
{'message': '\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/var/task/lego/bricks/tableau/workbook.py", line 65, in refresh_extracts\n    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)\n  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output\n    **kwargs).stdout\n  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run\n    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)\nsubprocess.CalledProcessError: Command \'***REDACTED***\' returned non-zero exit status 1.\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/var/task/jarvis/event_triggered/refresh_dashboard.py", line 21, in refresh_dashboard\n    workbook.refresh_extracts()\n  File "/var/task/lego/bricks/tableau/workbook.py", line 73, in refresh_extracts\n    traceback.format_exc()))\n  File "/var/task/lego/power_functions/error_handling/graceful_fail.py", line 16, in graceful_fail\n    raise RuntimeError(\'This is a graceful fail, notifications sent based on attributes.\')\nRuntimeError: This is a graceful fail, notifications sent based on attributes.\n'}
```

This could be a function, lambda, etc. that you pass through the logging formatter.

Comment: I thought about doing something like this (yours is better though), and while it would work, how would I pass this to the ```logging.Formatter```? That's what's got me lost

Comment: Whenever you call your logger, that's where you get to pass it the message that you intend to have logged. So wherever that code is, add the above check/conversion to modify the message string before it makes it down into the internal formatting code. Do you have any code to show us how you are actually calling the log funciton(s) ?

Comment: So do something like: logging.info(correct_text('my_message'))?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Let the correction function run before the potentially bad string makes it into the log functions.